# Finding duplicates and inserting them to a separate table

Tags: sql, insert, duplicates

I have a table

```
Id int
Post code int
Suburb varchar
State varchar
```

I need to be able find the duplicates of the combined `(post code, suburb, state)`

And insert them into a desperate table that records incorrect data

```
Eg
Id int
Post code int
Suburb varchar
State varchar
```

Comment: What database engine do you use?

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO IncorrectResults (PostCode, Suburb, State)
SELECT PostCode, Suburb, State
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY PostCode, Suburb, State
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```